# How to prove the comparison principle of this parabolic partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, parabolic-pde

[image: the comparison principle]

Here $H$ is a positive uniformly convex function. I came across this comparison principle while studying the paper. Maybe the author thought it was easy to prove so he omitted the proof, but I failed to give a proof. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What text is this from? What the version of the maximum principle has the author proved? Should $\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha$ be $\nabla_\beta \nabla_\alpha H$? I also assume that $\nabla$ is the Levi-Cevita connection on $\mathbb S^n$?

Comment: @JackT Sorry, I'll add some information. This is from the paper: "A logarithmic Gauss curvature flow and the Minkowski problem". In the paper, the author did not prove the maximum principle. Yes, there is a typo here. Yes, here $\nabla$ represents the connection on the unit sphere.

Comment: Link to this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144900000536?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-9&rr=8013db6d3a123451